# 3 level nested sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I'm trying to implement a 3 level nested sort. Basically I have four columns:

```
 A   |  B  |  C  |  D
 --- | --- | --- | ---
 bob | GOOD|  1  |
 kat | BAD |     | 24
 bob | OK  |     | 15
 bob | GOOD|  20 |
 bob | OK  |     | 10
 bob | OK  |  5  |
```

I have three levels of sorting needed...first level Column A ASC, 2nd level is case sorting on column B, and the third level I need to sort based on values from C & D if B = 'GOOD' and sort based on C if B is any other value.

What I currently have is:

```
ORDER
    BY A,
    CASE
        WHEN B ='GOOD' THEN 1 
        WHEN B = 'OK' THEN 2 
        WHEN B = 'BAD' THEN 3
    END, C
```

However this only sorts the third level based on values of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another case statement:

```
ORDER BY A,
         CASE B WHEN 'GOOD' THEN 1 
                WHEN 'OK' THEN 2 
                WHEN 'BAD' THEN 3
         END,
         CASE B WHEN 'GOOD' THEN C ELSE D END
```

In the sample data no row ever seems to have values for both C and D. If this is really the case, you could simplify things using `coalesce`:

```
ORDER BY A,
         CASE B WHEN 'GOOD' THEN 1 
                WHEN 'OK' THEN 2 
                WHEN 'BAD' THEN 3
         END,
         COALESCE(C, D)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right

```
ORDER BY A,
    CASE
        WHEN B ='GOOD' THEN 1 
        WHEN B = 'OK' THEN 2 
        WHEN B = 'BAD' THEN 3
    END, C,
    CASE WHEN B ='GOOD' THEN D END
```

Comment: I actually need columns C & D merged and then sorted when B = 'GOOD' but that's close!